# Deeplink url takes to play store/app store but not opening app if installed

Tags: android, ios, iphone, deep-linking

My deeplink url is redirecting me to the play store/ app store even the app is installed. But its working fine if open through slack, it opening the app from slack. But not working on facebook or chrome. Does someone knows the answer?

Comment: Deep link behaviour can be different according to the User Agent of the browser where you made the click in.
E.g. click within Slack may behave differently than a click within Safari browser.

Which deep link method are you trying to use? one which platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different behaviours between the different apps. Android Chrome for example works with intents and not URI scheme, Facebook usually doesn't like people leaving their app so some of the redirections are blocked.
For iOS you have different issues and different problems because Apple started blocking redirection to the app from advanced versions of iOS, unless you are using Universal links.

What I am trying to say is that I suggest using a 3rd party solution that can do all those workarounds for you.

Check https://www.appsflyer.com/product/one-link-deep-linking
- for more info

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But You did say "chrome works with intents and not uri scheme", I didnt get that. The scheme i found in every doc is either http or https. Could you share me a link which could solve my doubt..

Comment: You can check your apps deeplink works using adb command:
[adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d <url>]

More info for Chrome you can see here:
(https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)

Comment: yeah thats opening the app. But I dont know how to use that in androidmanifest.xml.
im using host: <url>, pathPrefix: <my path to the game>, scheme : <https>. But thats not working.

Comment: The manifest configuration is the same, the difference is what you put behind the link you click in Chrome and for that use the guide I linked above.
It should start with "intent://" and then add different params....